# Update View in Access not updating record even though return value in VB.Net return 1

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm stuck on this problem and cannot seem to fix it, my code below runs and and checkinsert returns 1 if one record is updated or 0 if none, problem is in Access the table column is not updated.

I cannot find why its not working, so i'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can spot the problem.

If I run the update View in Access, it works OK.

```
UPDATE tblStudentNameAndScore 
SET tblStudentNameAndScore.QuizCount = QuizCount+1, 
tblStudentNameAndScore.TimeLastQuestionAsked = Now()
WHERE tblStudentNameAndScore.StudentID=[?];
```

VB.Net

```
Public Function UpdateStudentScoreIfAnswerCorrect(ByVal studentId As String) As String
            Try
                Dim strAccessConn As String = _appConfigDbConn
                Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strAccessConn)
                cn.Open()
                Dim da As New OleDbCommand("qryUpdateStudentScore", cn)
                da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                'da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentId)
                da.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = studentId
                Dim checkinsert As New Integer
                checkinsert = da.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If checkinsert > 0 Then
                    Return "Success"
                End If
                cn.Close()
                cn.Dispose()
                Return "Fail"
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New ApplicationException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString())
            End Try
        End Function
```

I'm using Access 2010 and VB.NET Express

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your exact code and it seemed to work. Maybe my connection string was a bit different, but it worked in my test.

My connection string:
Dim strAccessConn As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\555\Test For StackOverflow.accdb"

Comment: Hi Yosem, thanks, just tried hard coding the sql into code, still get return value of 1, but table not updated.

Comment: Found the problem, once I moved the database out of project folder, updates worked. Not sure why

Comment: Found the problem, changed connection string from Source=|DataDirectory|\StudentQuizDB.accdb to C:\Users\**\**\**\**\StudentQuizDB.accdb and now works, if anyone can explain why changing the connection string made it work, it would be appreciated.